# Trimming Quadrilateral Into Rectangle Script

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

one of the time consuming process in my work flow is to correct distorted geometric shapes. This usually require wrap rectangular images into quadrilateral and then crop it back to rectangle - and we know cropping precise rectangle without leaving white corner edges can be difficult and frustrating. My question would be, did anyone figure a script to do the cropping for human beings? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a corner pin, like effect but in inverse? The crop tool can do this directly.